# Firebase data duplicate issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a React TODO app with backend firebase. The issue i'm stuck in is that the data sent from the firebase RTD is appending twice when after updating or deleting a node from the firebase RTD.

**State:**

```
// Initialize state
this.state = {
    todos: []
}
```

This is my `getTodos` function which is responsible for reading data, called inside `componentDidMount`:

```
getTodos () {
    firebase.database().ref('todos').on('value', (todo) => {
        const todos = todo.val();
        // Iterate through keys
        Object.keys(todos).map(todoItem => {                
            let todo = todos[todoItem];
            // Update the todos array
            this.setState({
                todos: [...this.state.todos, todo]
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Rendering section:

```
<tbody>
{
  this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
     return (
        <tr key={index}>
           <td>{index + 1}</td>
           <td>{todo.title}</td>
           <td>{todo.date}</td>
           <td align="center">
           <button className="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onClick={this.assignID.bind(this)}>
                   <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i>
               </button> &nbsp;
               <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={this.removeTodo.bind(this)}>
                   <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
               </button>
                </td>
         </tr>
          )
        })
      }
    </tbody>
}
```

The **result** (Before deleting a TODO):
[image]

After deleting a TODO:
[image]

I tried resetting `todos` state length to zero and then calling `getTodos`, but that didn't solve the issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not clearing the existing contents of the `todos` in the state. Also: you're updating the state at every iteration of the loop, which is inefficient.

```
firebase.database().ref('todos').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    var todos = [];
    snapshot.forEach((todo) => {
        todos.push(todo.val());
    });
    this.setState({
        todos: todos
    })
})
```

Comment: I tried to use this.setState outside the loop
 `Object.keys(todos).map(todoItem => {                
                todo = todos[todoItem];
            })
            this.setState({
                todos: [...this.state.todos, todo]
            })`
But it is giving me only the first item in the database

Comment: My code builds an array of `todos` first, and then set that entire array to the state after the loop.